# ionic select first option from dynamic values

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to select first option in ionic select 
I write condition with indexs which if index is 0 checked =  true still not working
here is my Code:

```
<ion-item>
            <ion-label>Venue Name</ion-label>
            <ion-select [(ngModel)]="venue_name">
                <ion-option *ngFor="let title of venues; let i = index" value="title.venue_id" checked="(i == 0) ? true : null">
                    {{title.venue_name}} 
                </ion-option>
            </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This

```
value="title.venue_id" checked="(i == 0) ? true : null"
```

Should be

```
[value]="title.venue_id" [selected]="i===0"
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-first-select)**

Comment: Thanks Brother its Working

Comment: @AmmadNazir, Glad to here that, please upvote and accept the answer :)